# How do I access from template class A a struct declared as private field in template B class in c++?

Tags: c++, oop, member-access

There is following c++ raw code:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class A {
 private:
  // here I want to access B::SomeStruct to create SomeStruct field in class A
};

template<typename T>
class B {
 private:
  template<typename Tp>
  friend class A;

  struct SomeStruct {
    void some_field;
  };
};
```

In class A I want to create a field with the type of `SomeStruct` - struct declared in class B as a private member. Does it even possible?

**Restrictions:**

1. Forbidden to create a global struct, accessible both A and B classes.
2. Forbidden to create any public fields in class B.

Comment: Which `B::SomeStruct`? `B<T>::SomeStruct`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo, B<T>::SomeStruct, actually.

Comment: @TedLyngmo ,I just want to create a SomeStruct field in A class, I think(hope) template specialization does not matters.

Comment: Please see my answer below and see if that does what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be one way. All `B`:s befriends all `A`:s and `A<T>` has a `B<T>::SomeStruct` member:

```
template<typename T>
class B {
private:
    template<typename Tp>
    friend class A;

    struct SomeStruct {};
};

template<typename T>
class A {
private:
    // 'typename' prior to dependent type name 'B<T>::SomeStruct':
    typename B<T>::SomeStruct ss;
};
```